# Numpy concatenate lists where first column is in range n

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I am trying to select all rows in a numpy matrix named `matrix` with shape `(25323, 9)`, where the values of the first column are inside the range of `start` and `end` for each tuple on the list `range_tuple`. Ultimately, I want to create a new numpy matrix with the result where `final` has a shape of `(n, 9)`. The following code returns this error: `TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index`. I have also tried initializing `final` with `numpy.zeros((1,9))` and used `np.concatenate` but get similar results. I do get a compiled result when I use `final.append(result)` instead of using `np.concatenate` but the shape of the matrix gets lost. I know there is a proper solution to this problem, any help would be appreciated.

```
  final = []
  for i in range_tuples:
    copy = np.copy(matrix)
    start = i[0]
    end = i[1]
    result = copy[(matrix[:,0] < end) & (matrix[:,0] > start)]
    final = np.concatenate(final, result)

  final = np.matrix(final)
```

Comment: `concatenate` takes a list of arrays, and an axis number.  You try to give it two array.  It's objecting to using the 2nd array as a number.  Oh, and don't use `concatenate` like this.  It's slow and hard to initialize.  Use list append.

Comment: Just to be clear, each `result` will be (n1, 9) shape, where `n1` can differ?  And you want the result to be one (n,9) where `n` is the sum of all those `n1`?  Have you tried `vstack` to join the list of arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [33]: arr                                                                                   
Out[33]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17],
       [18, 19, 20],
       [21, 22, 23]])
In [34]: tups = [(0,6),(3,12),(9,10),(15,14)]                                                  
In [35]: alist=[] 
    ...: for start, stop in tups: 
    ...:     res = arr[(arr[:,0]<stop)&(arr[:,0]>=start), :] 
    ...:     alist.append(res) 
    ...:
```

check the list; note that elements differ in shape; some are 1 or 0 rows.  It's a good idea to test these edge cases.

```
In [37]: alist                                                                                 
Out[37]: 
[array([[0, 1, 2],
        [3, 4, 5]]), array([[ 3,  4,  5],
        [ 6,  7,  8],
        [ 9, 10, 11]]), array([[ 9, 10, 11]]), array([], shape=(0, 3), dtype=int64)]
```

`vstack` joins them:

```
In [38]: np.vstack(alist)                                                                      
Out[38]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 3,  4,  5],
       [ 3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11],
       [ 9, 10, 11]])
```

Here `concatenate` also works, because default axis is 0, and all inputs are already 2d.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
final = np.empty((0,9))
for start, stop in range_tuples:
    result = matrix[(matrix[:,0] < end) & (matrix[:,0] > start)]
    final = np.concatenate((final, result))
```

The first is to initialize `final` as a numpy array. The first argument to concatenate has to be a python list of the arrays, see [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html). In your code it interprets the `result` variable as the value for the parameter `axis`

*Notes*

- I used tuple deconstruction to make the loop clearer
- the copy is not needed
- appending lists can be faster. The final result can afterwards be obtained through [reshaping](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html), if `result` is always of the same length.

Answer (score 1):

I would simply create a boolean mask to select rows that satisfy required conditions.

EDIT: I missed that you are working with `matrix` (as opposite to `ndarray`). Answer was edited for `matrix`.

Assume following input data:

```
matrix = np.matrix([[1, 2, 3], [5, 6, 7], [2, 1, 7], [3, 4, 5], [8, 9, 0]])
range_tuple = [(0, 2), (1, 4), (1, 9), (5, 9), (0, 100)]
```

Then, first, I would convert `range_tuple` to a `numpy.ndarray`:

```
range_mat = np.matrix(range_tuple)
```

Now, create the mask:

```
mask = np.ravel((matrix[:, 0] > range_mat[:, 0]) & (matrix[:, 0] < range_mat[:, 1]))
```

Apply the mask:

```
final = matrix[mask]  # or matrix[mask].copy() if you intend to modify matrix
```

To check:

```
print(final)
[[1 2 3]
 [2 1 7]
 [8 9 0]]
```

---

If length of `range_tuple` can be *different* from the number of rows in the `matrix`, then do this:

```
n = min(range_mat.shape[0], matrix.shape[0])
mask = np.pad(
    np.ravel(
        (matrix[:n, 0] > range_mat[:n, 0]) & (matrix[:n, 0] < range_mat[:n, 1])
    ),
    (0, matrix.shape[0] - n)
)
final = matrix[mask]
```